# Given a non-empty string like "Code" return a string like "CCoCodCode"

Tags: python, string, function, return

```
def string_splosion(str):
    result = ""
                                                   
    for i in range(len(str)):
        result = result + str[:i + 1]
    return result
```

I got this answer from codingBat. Can someone explain this code to me? I am having trouble understanding what the :i + 1 does in str{0:i + 1] code.
Thanks

Tried multitiude of things to solve the problem. But keep getting it wrong.

Comment: print(string_splosion('Code'))
print(string_splosion('abc'))                 This is what I was trying to print out
print(string_splosion('ab'))

Comment: "Can someone explain this code to me?" No, because [there is no way that we can know what you need to know, or why you don't already understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894). Start by trying to check carefully what the code does, step by step. You should have a clear expectation in mind for what each part of the code does; if not, then pick one specific thing where you don't have that expectation, [try to look for existing information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) (for example, by following a Python tutorial), and then ask **specifically**.

Comment: (The same applies to your previous question, BTW.)

Comment: What previous question?

Comment: The [previous one that you asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75583101/explaining-how-to-remove-duplicates).

Comment: Ok. Understood on being more specific

Comment: Please let us know if you are asking the following question: 'I do not understand the role of the colon ":", in "str[ :i + 1]" which appears in the code below, which I got from codingBat.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain what that colon does and/or direct me to some URL(s) where I could learn more about it.'

Answer (score -1):

If you simply print `i` and `result` in the for loop, you should able to understand the main idea. Also, you could rewrite `str[:i + 1]` with `str[0:i+1]` which is probably more self-explanatory.

Here is what you should get if you print the `i` and `result`:

```
0 c
1 cco
2 ccocod
3 ccocodcode
```

Focus on the "added" part for each step. You see that it starts with only 1 character, since id adds `str[0:1]` in the first step. If you don't know about slice notation, check this thread: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

I hope it's helpful.